# passing a parameter into dpkg -i?

Tags: parameters, installation, debian, dpkg

Is there any way to pass a parameter into dpkg -i that can then be used by preinst and postinst? I've looked into this and was wondering if I could refer to these parameters with $1 or $2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot pass a parameter that way.

You can set an environmental variable this way

```
$ VARIABLE=foo dpkg --install package.deb
```

or (much better) use [debconf](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/debconf_specification.html) to ask questions to the user.

Answer (score 3):

You know, the parameters of an application are visible with the `debconf-get-selections` command. i.e. `debconf-get-selections | grep myapp`

Assume there're two parameters available for your deb package, so you can perform non-interactive install like this:

```
echo myapp myapp/param1 string 8888 | debconf-set-selections
echo myapp myapp/param2 boolean true | debconf-set-selections
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i blablabla.deb
```

Now, you can use `param1` and `param2` in your preinst and postinst.

Comment: Thanks.. This worked...! :) Those interested to know more, refer - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man7/debconf.7.html and https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debconf-doc/debconf-devel.7.en.html